# Access Custom Setting field value

Tags: custom-field, customsetting, custom

I have a custom setting titled 'Authentication' and a field named 'token'.

I need to access the value stored in 'token' in Apex, but I'm not sure how to do so. I'm aware of the get Instance() method, but haven't been able to get it to work yet - what value do you pass to getInstance?

There will only ever be one value in the 'token' field.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: list custom setting or hierarchy custom setting?  If List custom setting, you need to know the key of the record which will be the value of the name field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Hierarchy setting, use getOrgDefaults() to get the default value. If you use a List setting, then you need to pass in the name of the value you want to retrieve. Lists can store multiple rows of data, each one uniquely identified by its name. It doesn't matter what you name it, so long as the value is consistent.

Comment: Also if Hierarchy you can use `getInstance(userInfo.getUserID())` if you store settings by user